# Want to open whatsapp chat activity with a specific number i never had chatted with this number

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I tried a lot of times to do that by Intent, i used this code

```
 Uri mUri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "000000000000");
                        Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, mUri);
                    mIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    mIntent.putExtra("chat",true);
                    startActivity(mIntent);
```

but this mehod never work when i want to open chat with a number i never had chatted with

Answer (score 0):

I guess its not possible to do so as it may lead to misuse of the API, hence WhatsApp developers have not provided this functionality. Imagine it will lead to so much of spamming activity!